# Delete Duplicated Sublists within a List in Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, duplicates, sublist

For instance say,

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

I would like it to instead print

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1},{ {1, 1}}
```

I have tried `DeleteDuplicates[list]` and that worked to no avail. Any ideas? A `loop` and comparing each element would work but would take to much memory as the number of `sublists` I have are based on (high) factorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get (*Mathematica* 8):

```
In[1]:  list = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}};
        DeleteDuplicates[list]

Out[1]: {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

Comment: I must be making an error somewhere else in the code... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another command to consider is `Union`. When it acts on a single list, it will delete duplicates and sort the outcome.

```
In[1]:= Union[{{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}]
Out[1]= {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}
```